Pythonのinput()を実行しても入力フォームが現れない。
実行環境
Chrome OSのcrostini上のDebian12
テキストエディタ: VS Code
VS Codeの拡張機能にJupyterを使用
importしたライブラリ: requests、BeautifulSoup4
起こった不具合
第1セルを実行して、その次に第2セルを実行した際にセルの下に入力するところが表示されない
期待している動作
第2セルを実行したときに、セルの下に入力するところを表示させたい
再現手順
以下のコードをVS CodeのJupyter NotebookかJupyter Labで上から順に実行する
第1セル
# 商品名からコードを取得
product_name = input("Please input product name")
code = get_code_from_product_name(product_name)

第2セル
if code:
    print(f"CODE: {code}")
else:
    print("商品が見つかりませんでした")

Google Colaboratoryで検証した結果
product_name = input()を実行したところ、下の画像のようになった


「再現手順
以下のコードをJupyter NotebookかJupyter Labで上から順に実行する。 」では情報が足りないです。期待している動作がなにで、そのためにあなたはどんな操作をして、どうなると期待していて、しかし実際はどうなったのか、どいう情報が必要です。

例えばGoogle Colaboratoryでproduct_name = input()とだけ入力して試すのと何か違いがあるのか確かめてみてはどうでしょう？ あるいは今の環境でも第3セルをproduct_name = input()だけにして試してみるとか？

もしかしたら、この記事と回答が当てはまるのかもしれませんね。How to give jupyter cell standard input in python?, 回答 該当部分の翻訳：「Visual Studio Code を使用している場合、入力は画面の上部にポップアップ表示されるバーに入力する必要があります (セルのすぐ下ではありません)。」

更に同じような説明がこちらの記事にもありましたので、そういうことなのだと思われます。Show question/input in vscode jupyter notebook output

@kunif リンク先の記事が当てはまりました！解決です！

「Amazonで販売されている商品のASINをスクレイピングで収集したい」という行為は対象サイトの利用規約に違反しているように思われますが確認済でしょうか？

@merino はい、確認済みです。未ログイン状態だったら法的処罰は受けないと思われますし、頻度に気をつければ大丈夫かと。ご迷惑をおかけしてはいけないので、頻度などには気をつけます。 octoparse.jp/blog/legal-considerations-while-scraping-amazon

利用規約には「アマゾンサービスを利用することにより、お客様は本利用規約に同意することになります」とあったのでログインしているかどうかは関係ないような気がします。また「データ収集・抽出ツール」の使用そのものが禁止されているようです。法的な事は分かりませんがアマゾンサイトをスクレイピングするコードを公開するのは良くないかもしれません。

@merino そうかもしれませんね。スクレイピングするコードは削除して簡潔にしました。

おそらく、このコードは正常に動いているはずです。
Pythonのinput()はこれといったダイヤログが出る、フォームがCUI上に出現することはありません。
実行すると何も動かないように見えると思いますが、その状態で文字を入力すると無事プログラムが動くはずです。
実際、こちらの環境(Python3.10)ではフォームは現れませんでしたが無事に動作しました。

input()に入力時にシェルに表示したい文字を渡すと入力待ちの時間に表示することができます。
input(“商品名を入力:“)

これでわかりやすくなると思います

VSCodeを利用しているので、画面上部のホップアップに入力用のバーが出現しました！
